# Sum operation in SQL

Tags: sql

I created two tables one " Employees " Table and " Department " Table.

In **Department Table** Column Names are :

```
Dept_ID, Dept_Name
```

Here I assigned Primary Key for `Dept_ID`

In **Employees Table** Column Names are :

```
Emp_ID, FName, LName, City, Emp_Salary, Dept_ID
```

Here I assigned Primary Key for `Emp_ID` & Foreign Key for `Dept_ID` references to
`Department(Dept_ID)`

I want to know the department name which is earning the 2nd Highest Salaries. I need syntax

Please help

Comment: What have you already tried? If nothing then I suggest you try a SQL tutorial / book before posting.

Comment: When you just need the syntax and everything else is fine, the official manual of whatever RDBMS you are using is of great help.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle this would result in the following query:

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name
FROM (
  SELECT rownum AS position, a.*
  FROM (
    SELECT Dept_ID, SUM(Emp_Salary) as Total_Salary
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY Dept_ID
    ORDER BY Total_Salary DESC
  ) a
) b
INNER JOIN department d ON d.Dept_ID = b.Dept_ID
WHERE b.position = 2
```

You can see a working Oracle SQLFiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5602/17

For completeness, if your DBMS is MySQL, this query will do the trick:

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name
FROM (
  SELECT Dept_ID, SUM(Emp_Salary) as Total_Salary
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY Dept_ID
  ORDER BY Total_Salary DESC
  LIMIT 1,1
) a
INNER JOIN department d ON d.Dept_ID = a.Dept_ID
```

You can see a working MySQL SQLFiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/738e0/15

Comment: @Nagaraj What do you mean by SQL? This *is* SQL and should work on a variety of DBMS'es.

Comment: I am Sorry, I presented this code on Oracle 11g but there, it didn'tworked. I see your code working perfect in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/738e0/15.

Comment: @Nagaraj I have edited my answer to include the Oracle version of the query

Answer (score 0):

If this is MSSQL try this query:

```
with salary as --sum all salaries for all departments
(
    select d.Dept_ID, SUM(e.Emp_Salary) as SalarySum
    from Department d
    inner join Employees e on e.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID
    group by d.Dept_ID
),
max as --select maximum salary
(
    select  MAX(s.SalarySum) as Max
    from salary s
)

select top 1 * 
from salary s
where s.SalarySum < (select top 1 m.Max from max m) -- only select those that are lower than max
order by s.SalarySum desc
```

Comment: First one is executed and the rest not

Comment: Sorry was typo there. Try again (and it will work only in MSSQL!)

Comment: over complicated for selecting the 2nd row